# Are there Secret Rooms in Greed Mode?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

In the Afterbirth DLC there is a new feature called *Greed Mode*.

According to the [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Greed_Mode):

> Each floor has a Curse Room, a Devil Room, a double-wide Shop, and an exit room all connected to a main double-height arena room with a button in the center. An already unlocked Treasure Room with a silver doorframe and a normal locked treasure room are also available.

In the shop, however, it's possible to buy the *[X-Ray Vision](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/X-Ray_Vision)* item, which reveals and opens all Secret Room and Super Secret Room entrances.

Before I waste my money, are there any *Secret Room* in the *Greed Mode*?

**UPDATE**:

The *Greed Mode* wikia page now states that:

> The level may also contain a Secret Room

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The blog post introducing Greed Mode](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/127517383219/lets-get-greedy%20The%20blog%20post%20introducing%20Greed%20Mode) lists all possible locations for Super Secret Rooms in Greed Mode:

- above the Shop
- to the right of the Treasure Rooms
- to the left of the Cursed and Devil room
- below the exit room

[image]

It doesn't mention normal Secret Rooms, so I think there are none in Greed Mode.

Comment: I'm sure that I've read that post a couple of months ago, and I've totally forgot it. Let me edit your answer adding the layout image.

Comment: The map is not entirely true, or old. There can be secret rooms on the left side of the store and the left side of the exit. If needed, I can link the yt videos of a few BoI LetsPlayers where you can clearly see that rooms can exist in other places too. Also, I think the secret room behind the devil room does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I created an account just to add my input as well. I can't comment on Powerlord's post but I also found a secret room. Mine was above the curse room and left of the shop. The only issue is that it was blocked by the cement wall blocks (similar to those around the black hearts in levels).

So unless you're flying and have a bomb handy I don't think that had a potential for entry. I found it with the Spelunker's Hat.

Also if you find a counterfeit penny in greed mode... You pretty much win.

Comment: This is a unique behaviour, the Secret Room always has a free door. This means that in Greed Mode it's not true anymore. Good to know, than you!

Comment: I found a secret room in the same place on the Shop level, to the left of the shop room. I hit a button with a Troll Bomb on the left of the shop and it opened the wall on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I finally bought the *X-Ray Vision* item, and it has never revealed and opened any Secret Room on any floor.

EDIT:

I also tried with the *[Blue Map](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Blue_Map)* (which shows *Secret* and *Super Secret Room* locations on the map) and I haven't found one.

If there are Super Secret Rooms in this mode they are very very rare.

EDIT2:

I've found a couple of **Super Secret Room** in my last run (having *X-Ray Vision*):

- on the left of the Silver Treasure Room
- under the Exit Room

So you can find them occasionally.

Comment: Not strictly true.  I ran into a Super Secret room above the shop room's left half on floor 1 when I had the X-Ray Vision item.

Comment: @Powerlord Oh, interesting, but I assume it was a rare case because I haven't found one in my whole run.

Comment: They were supposedly broken until a couple of patches ago, apparently almost never spawning and often trapping you inside when they did spawn. They should be much more frequent now.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Oh, good to know.